# Comparing the same images with different format(.jpg, .bmp, .png, etc)

Tags: ruby, image, image-processing, cmd

I need to check if 2 images have been modified. I have the original image which I input it through 2 different tools, finally resulting the 2nd image. 
The tools only alter the format of the image; the inputted image can be of any type (.jpg, .bmp, etc), and the first tool converts the image to .bmp and the second tool converts it to .png.
How can I check if the images display the same thing, with a certain threshold of course. (via cmd if possible, after that I'll write a script in Ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick can handle this by compare command.

Usage:

```
compare im1.png im2.bmp result.jpg
```

It marks the changed areas with red. After that you can easily check if it's changed or not.

Example: (Note that input images are from slightly different angles, so they are not the same.)

```
compare orig0.bmp orig1.jpg compare.jpg
```

orig0.bmp
[image]

orig1.jpg
[image]

compare.jpg
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, do you have any suggestions on how to implement this in Ruby?

Comment: I really don't know anything about Ruby sorry about that, but just read the image and split the RGB channels of both image. Then, compare R1-R2, G1-G2, B1-B2. This will give you the difference.